# How to illustrate simple scaling equation?

Tags: functions, notation

I'm making a map where it illustrates the stars closest to our sun. The closest one is $4.2 \text{ly}$ away and I chose to scale it to km on a map. It's easy to show on a map where $4.2 \text{ly}$ is $4.2 \text{km}$ but how do I illustrate this conversion in an equation?

$$\text{distance in km}  = 4.2 \text{ly} \cdot \bigg(\frac{9461000000000 \text{km}}{ 1 \text{ly}}\bigg)$$

What am I missing here?

I know the ratio for $\text{ly}$ to $\text{km}$ is $1:9461000000000$ but unsure how to illustrate my thinking.

Comment: I'm super confused. Did you make a map that's 4.2km long? If not, then your scale is going to be more than 1:9461000000000. If you're just marking "km" as units on your map, then why not just mark "ly" instead?

Comment: I'm using a map with a ruler function so it illustrates a line of 10km. And on this there's a point that's 4.2km from the beginning. It's to showcase the scale of the stars on a relatable level on earth

Comment: [Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(map)#The_terminology_of_scales): $\dfrac {4.2 \text {lighty} }{4.2 \text {km} } = \dfrac {1 \text {lighty} }{1 \text {km} }$

Comment: thank you very much!